# Selenium server - is 500 MB memory usage normal?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running the Selenium webdriver with the HTMLUnit driver. I start the driver:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar
```

Then I start Python and load a webpage. I am using HtmlUnit.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

The resultant memory usage for the server is 550 MB. This is twice my alloted memory usage and everything crashes.

Is this a normal memory usage or am I using it incorrectly? If this is the normal usage then I probably won't be able to use Selenium:( Memory is what I pay for where it is hosted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't run the standalone selenium server, but if you're looking for a way to increase the memory available, update your java command to the following :

```
java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar
```

See [-X Command-line Options](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html) for more details. (That link actually points to a non-standard JVM version, but the documentation for the java command line should be applicable.)